# How to resize button so it is mobile friendly and only shows the symbol?

Tags: html, css, button, mobile, media-queries

I am trying to resize my button so it is smaller, more mobile friendly, and only shows the symbol when minimized (versus the symbol and text).

The goal is to have the button appear on the same row as the header on the right-hand side. I also only want to show the symbol, while the text will disappear, only reappearing if the screen size is bigger.

I've tried adjusting the width through media queries and the positioning of the button, but haven't had any luck.

[Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y11wk.png)

```
<!-- Table  -->
<div class="container-fluid">

<!-- Mini Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="d-inline-block">Welcome!</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-add float-right" id="add invoice"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>Add Invoice</button>
     </div>
 </div>
<!-- End of Mini Row -->

#add-invoice {
   font-family: "FjallaOne-Regular";
   font-size: 1em !important;
   color: black;
   background-color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
   margin-top: 4.5em;
   margin-right: 1.75em;
 }

/* Media Queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   h3 {
     margin-left: -.25em    
   }
   #add-invoice {
     margin: -1em;
     margin-top: 4.5em;
   }
 }
```

Comment: set max width for a mobile device like #add-invoice{ max-width:70px}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your Button text on `span` tag & add a media query

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
   .btn span{display:none;}
 }

<!-- Mini Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="d-inline-block">Welcome!</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-add float-right" id="add invoice"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> <span>Add Invoice</span></button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/4tm968rz/4/

Answer (score 0):

Add span tag in button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-add float-right" id="add-invoice">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i><span>Add Invoice</span></button>
```

and than css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      #add-invoice span{
         display:none;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
#add-invoice {
   font-family: "FjallaOne-Regular";
   font-size: 1em !important;
   color: black;
   background-color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
   margin-top: 4.5em;
   margin-right: 1.75em;
 }

/* Media Queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   h3 {
     margin-left: -.25em    
   }
   #add-invoice {
     margin: -1em;
     margin-top: 4.5em;
     font-size: 0.5em !important;
   }
 }
```

```html
<!-- Table  -->
<div class="container-fluid">

<!-- Mini Row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="d-inline-block">Welcome!</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-add float-right" id="add invoice"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>Add Invoice</button>
     </div>
 </div>
<!-- End of Mini Row -->
```